# Summing data from array based on other array in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, matrix

I have two 2D numpy arrays (simplified in this example with respect to size and content) with identical sizes.

An ID matrix:

```
1 1 1 2 2
1 1 2 2 5
1 1 2 5 5
1 2 2 5 5
2 2 5 5 5
```

and a value matrix:

```
14.8 17.0 74.3 40.3 90.2
25.2 75.9  5.6 40.0 33.7
78.9 39.3 11.3 63.6 56.7
11.4 75.7 78.4 88.7 58.6
79.6 32.3 35.3 52.5 13.3
```

My goal is to *count* and *sum* the values from the second matrix grouped by the IDs from the first matrix:

```
1: (8, 336.8)
2: (9, 453.4)
5: (8, 402.4)
```

I can do this in a `for` loop but when the matrices have sizes in thousands instead of just 5x5 and thousands of unique ID's, it takes a lot of time to process.

**Does `numpy` have a clever method or a combination of methods for doing this?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach to get the counts for `ID` and `ID-based` summed values for `value` with a combination of [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) -

```
unqID,idx,IDsums = np.unique(ID,return_counts=True,return_inverse=True)

value_sums = np.bincount(idx,value.ravel())
```

To get the final output as a dictionary, you can use loop-comprehension to gather the summed values, like so -

```
{i:(IDsums[itr],value_sums[itr]) for itr,i in enumerate(unqID)}
```

Sample run -

```
In [86]: ID
Out[86]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2, 5],
       [1, 1, 2, 5, 5],
       [1, 2, 2, 5, 5],
       [2, 2, 5, 5, 5]])

In [87]: value
Out[87]: 
array([[ 14.8,  17. ,  74.3,  40.3,  90.2],
       [ 25.2,  75.9,   5.6,  40. ,  33.7],
       [ 78.9,  39.3,  11.3,  63.6,  56.7],
       [ 11.4,  75.7,  78.4,  88.7,  58.6],
       [ 79.6,  32.3,  35.3,  52.5,  13.3]])

In [88]: unqID,idx,IDsums = np.unique(ID,return_counts=True,return_inverse=True)
    ...: value_sums = np.bincount(idx,value.ravel())
    ...: 

In [89]: {i:(IDsums[itr],value_sums[itr]) for itr,i in enumerate(unqID)}
Out[89]: 
{1: (8, 336.80000000000001),
 2: (9, 453.40000000000003),
 5: (8, 402.40000000000003)}
```

Comment: Nice one! I was not aware of the `return_*` arguments for `np.unique`.

Comment: @Divakar: Thank You! This was exactly the kind of solution I was looking for with a good performance due to the vectorisation.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with a combination of a few simple methods:

1. use [`numpy.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to find each ID
2. create a boolean mask for each ID
3. sum the 1s in the mask (count) and the values where the mask is 1

This can look like this:

```
import numpy as np

ids = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
                [1, 1, 2, 2, 5],
                [1, 1, 2, 5, 5],
                [1, 2, 2, 5, 5],
                [2, 2, 5, 5, 5]])

values = np.array([[14.8, 17.0, 74.3, 40.3, 90.2],
                   [25.2, 75.9,  5.6, 40.0, 33.7],
                   [78.9, 39.3, 11.3, 63.6, 56.7],
                   [11.4, 75.7, 78.4, 88.7, 58.6],
                   [79.6, 32.3, 35.3, 52.5, 13.3]])


for i in np.unique(ids):  # loop through all IDs
    mask = ids == i  # find entries that match current ID
    count = np.sum(mask)  # number of matches
    total = np.sum(values[mask])  # values of matches
    print('{}: ({}, {:.1f})'.format(i, count, total))  #print result

# Output:
# 1: (8, 336.8)
# 2: (9, 453.4)
# 5: (8, 402.4)
```

Comment: Its exactly that nasty `for` loop I'm referring to in my question, I should have been more clear on that though.

Comment: I think there is not really a succint way of doing that without the for loop. It may be possible, but would likely lead to very unreadable code. If you only have a few unique IDs there should not be a too big performace hit by the for loop. Anyway, I will think about it for a while...

Comment: Looks like I was just proven wrong in [Divakar's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36643601/3005167).

Answer (score 0):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) has functionality to solve these kind of problems in an elegant and vectorized manner:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
group_by = npi.group_by(ID.flatten())
ID_unique, value_sums = group_by.sum(value.flatten())
ID_count = groupy_by.count
```

Note: if you want to compute the sum and count in order to compute a mean, there is also group_by.mean; plus a lot of other useful functionality.