# How to get sum of values in a numpy array based on another array with repetitive indices

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

```py
data_values = np.random.rand(10)
data_ind = np.random.randint(0,10,10)
    
data_values = (array([0.81444589, 0.57734696, 0.54130794, 0.22339518, 0.916973  ,
            0.14956333, 0.74504583, 0.36218693, 0.17958372, 0.47195214]),
    
data_ind = array([7, 5, 2, 2, 0, 6, 6, 1, 4, 3]))
```

Desired output:

```py
0 - 0.91693   
1 - 0.36218693  
2 - 0.54130794 + 0.22339518  
3 - 0.47195214  
4 - 0.17958372  
5 - 0.57734696  
6 -  0.14956333 + 0.74504583  
output = array([0.916973, 0.36218694, 0.7647031, 0.47195214, 0.17958371, 0.577347, 0.89460915, 0.8144459], dtype=float32)
```

I have written a long way

```py
nodal_values = np.zeros(8, dtype=np.float32)  
for nodes in range(8):  
    nodal_values[nodes] = np.sum(data_values[np.where(data == nodes)[0]])
```

The above method takes lot of time, whereas

```py
a = ((np.mgrid[:M,:N] == b)[0] * c).sum(axis=1)
```

gives memory error for large data with millions.

I am looking for an optimized way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please checkout [stackoverflow question guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to ask better questions, as well as properly format them.

---

### Options

#### Original code

This is what you want to optimize for large values of `N` (I took the liberty of editing your code so that it does not have hardcoded values and fixed a typo, `data_values` instead of `data`):

```
data_values = np.random.rand(N) 
data_ind = np.random.randint(0, N, N)

xsize = data_ind.max() + 1
nodal_values = np.zeros(xsize, dtype=np.float32)  
for nodes in range(xsize):  
    nodal_values[nodes] = np.sum(data_values[np.where(data_ind == nodes)[0]])
```

#### Slightly better version (for readability)

I created the following version which improves readability and takes away the use of `np.where`:

```
idx = np.arange(xsize)[:, None] == data_ind
nodal_values = [np.sum(data_values[idx[i]]) for i in range(xsize)] # Python list
```

#### Much better version

I implemented the accepted answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643216/summing-data-from-array-based-on-other-array-in-numpy) (be sure to check it out to understand it better) by @Divakar to your case:

```
_, idx, _ = np.unique(data_ind, return_counts=True, return_inverse=True)
nodal_values = np.bincount(idx, data_values) # Same shape and type as your version
```

---

### Comparison

Using your original values:

```
data_values = np.array([0.81444589, 0.57734696, 0.54130794, 0.22339518, 0.916973, 0.14956333, 0.74504583, 0.36218693, 0.17958372, 0.47195214])
data_ind = np.array([7, 5, 2, 2, 0, 6, 6, 1, 4, 3])
```

I got the following performance using `timeit` module (`mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each`):

```
Original code: 49.2 +- 11.1 ns
Much better version: 45.2 +- 4.98 ns
Slightly better version: 36.4 +- 2.81 ns
```

For really small values of `N`, i.e, 1 to 10, there is no significant difference. However, for big ones, there is no question as to which one to use; both versions with for-loops take too long, while the vectorized implementation does it extremely fast.

[image: Small N comparison]
[image: Big N comparison]

#### Code to test it out

```
import numpy as np
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def original_code():
    xsize = data_ind.max() + 1
    nodal_values = np.zeros(xsize, dtype=np.float32)
    for nodes in range(xsize):
        nodal_values[nodes] = np.sum(data_values[np.where(data_ind == nodes)[0]])

def much_better():
    _, idx, _ = np.unique(data_ind, return_counts=True, return_inverse=True)
    nodal_values = np.bincount(idx, data_values)

def slightly_better():
    xsize = data_ind.max() + 1
    idx = np.arange(xsize)[:, None] == data_ind
    nodal_values = [np.sum(data_values[idx[i]]) for i in range(xsize)]

sizes = [i*5 for i in range(1, 7)]
original_code_times = np.zeros((len(sizes),))
slightly_better_times = np.zeros((len(sizes),))
much_better_times = np.zeros((len(sizes),))
for i, N in enumerate(sizes):
    print(N)
    data_values = np.random.rand(N)
    data_ind = np.random.randint(0, N, N)

    # Divided by 100 repeats to get average
    original_code_times[i] = timeit.timeit(original_code, number=100) / 100
    much_better_times[i] = timeit.timeit(much_better, number=100) / 100
    slightly_better_times[i] = timeit.timeit(slightly_better, number=100) / 100

# Multiply by 1000 to get everything in ms
original_code_times *= 1000
slightly_better_times *= 1000
much_better_times *= 1000

# %%
plt.figure(dpi=120)
plt.title("Small N's")
plt.plot(sizes, original_code_times, label="Original code")
plt.plot(sizes, slightly_better_times, label="Slightly better")
plt.plot(sizes, much_better_times, label="Much better")
plt.ylabel("Time [ms]")
plt.xlabel("N")
plt.xticks(sizes)
plt.legend()
plt.savefig("small_N.png", dpi=120)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

I hope this helps anyone who may stumble upon this.